# Is there a commonly recognized placeholder airline name?

Tags: airlines

I'm wondering if there is a **common placeholder name for an airline**, either implying a legally disclosed or fictional entity, which is frequently used?

For instance, I've seen the terms containing 'widgets' used very often in an economics context. John Doe is often used in legal cases.

<sup>*"Placeholder names are words that can refer to objects or people whose names are temporarily forgotten, irrelevant, or unknown in the context in which they are being discussed." -Wikipedia</sup>

Comment: I'm going to ask my sister Alice to ask her friend Bob about this, but she has been charged with mopery due to financial irregularities surrounding her purchase of Blackacre in Outerstan, so I'll need a few cartons of Morley cigarettes from BigCo to bribe the Lord High Executioner.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Alice can't talk to Bob. Carol is listening.

Comment: [Here](http://www.fly-belts.com/blog/top-ten-fictional-made-up-airlines/)'s a little list but I'm not really convinced. I don't think there is _that one_ airline name that immediately pops into one's mind when thinking about a placeholder. Like "ACME" for a company, "John/Jane Doe" for a person, "foo/bar" for an arbitrary string (in programming), or "42" for an arbitrary number. But "Oceanic" seems popular albeit I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @Jamiec _Eve_ is listening.

Comment: @DavidRicherby _Eve_'s dropping.

Comment: The thing about "widgets" is we know almost nothing about what they are. Any kind of airline is already in a much more specific industry than a widget manufacturer. I suppose you _don't_ want a name of an airline from a particular work of fiction, that is, you want something analogous to John Doe and _not_ John McClane.

Comment: @PerlDuck 'Oceanic' was the name of the airline in [_Lost_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_(TV_series)). Remember not to get on flight 815.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I just looked again, and you're right it *is* Eve. You obviously got the pun/joke, I've always seen Carol (or Catherine) as the third party, but it really is more commonly referred to as Eve.

Comment: @Jamiec It depends what the third party's doing. If they're eavesdropping, they're usually called Eve; if it's a consensual 3-way communication, then a name beginning with C would make sense.

Comment: Another analogy is that [example.com](http://example.com) is a domain name that was specifically created to be used as an example in documentation. Hence, its use is safe in the help feature of this website.

Comment: http://fictional-airlines.wikia.com/wiki/Fictional_Airlines_Wikia

Comment: @Jamiec: Here's the full-cast of the exciting Cryptography Games, if you're interested: https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters

Comment: *Sandpiper Air* from [Wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_%281990_TV_series%29) ? :-)

Comment: "Fly-EZ: The airline that can't *afford* to crash."

Comment: @Jamiec *Mallory* is inserting himself into the communications (man-in-the-middle). Alice, Bob, Carol and Dave are traditionally the parties considered privy to the communications, whereas Eve and Mallory are not privy but try anyway using various means. Sometimes they try to break things, sometimes they just want to listen.

Comment: If you want to attempt to be humorous you could use High Flyer Airways or Mile High Airlines.

Answer (score 29):

I think [Oceanic Airlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_Airlines) is well known fictive airline. It is used widely in Lost and also Alias, Castle, JAG, Category 6: Day of Destruction and in Executive Decision (the material from this movie was reused in a lot of low budget movies).

Comment: You do **not** want to fly on that airline!

Comment: But it ensures a weird adventure!

Comment: I don't think I had ever heard of this one.

Comment: Probably you should stop flying yourself and watch the onboard-entertainment :p

Comment: As long as Tom Hanks isn't your pilot, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: @GdD Why not? The posters say it has a perfect safety record? :-)

Answer (score 17):

**I would suggest Acme.**

At least within certain communities, Acme is a generally recognized placeholder name for airlines. This includes Acme Airlines, Acme Red, Acme Giant, Acme Express, etc. This convention is often used in the podcast world as a means of referring to one's employing company without directly naming the company but still differentiating between many of the real airlines. However, these names may have outgrown their placeholder status in some cases and may now be synonymous with the names of the real airlines.

[image]

<sup>Artwork from the [APG](http://airlinepilotguy.com/) community</sup>

Comment: That's a really nice logo for **A** **C**ompany **M**oving **E**verything. Looks cute.

Comment: I remember the old Warner Brother's cartoon's used to use ACME for just about every company you could imagine.  I'd have to think one of them was an airline at some point or another.

Comment: @JayCarr Considering that (IIRC) Wile E. Coyote was able to procure *rockets* from Acme Corp, I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if they are into airlines as well.

Comment: Credit for this Acme logo should go to The Airline Pilot Guy, Capt. Jeff and his crew. http://airlinepilotguy.com Great podcast, by the way.

Comment: @thetoolman Agreed, though it wasn't created by Jeff Nielsen but someone from the community (I forget who).

Answer (score 12):

Why not use a variation on the "generic company names" from
[the aforementioned Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name#Companies_and_organizations)?

For example, Acme Airlines, Ace Airlines, XYZ Air.

If it's a small airline, Mom and Pop Air.

Note that in the example "XYZ Widget Company," the idea is to obscure
not only the identity of the company, but also to obscure what they *do.*
Since you have stated you want an airline, the "widget" part of the
company name is redundant. That's why I suggested simply replacing
"Widget Company" with "Airlines" or "Air".

If the generic airline is not associated with a particular market,
an alternative is to use a placeholder geographical name:
Utopia Airlines or Air Ruritania for a national-scale airline,
Podunk Airlines for a local operation.

Comment: The small scale operation will be named Mom and Pop Air but will have Utopia livery on their aircraft and do business as Utopia Connection...

Comment: @MichaelHampton **Yes!** :-)